# How to check if rule is already in iptables

Tags: python, shell, grep, raspberry-pi

I'm having a problem with my python script that's supposed to check if a certain rule is written in iptables, and if not add it there.

```
def blockip(packet_ip):

   cmd="sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s "+packet_ip+" -j DROP"
   print cmd

   if ["$(sudo cat /sbin/iptables --list | grep -- packet_ip)"]:
        print "Already Blocked"
    else:
        subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
        print packet_ip + " Has been Blocked"
```

Here is my function that should take care of it but it does not work and writes the same rule multiple times in iptables if same `packet_ip` is met. Running on RPI btw if it makes a difference.

Comment: `if ["$(command)"]` is not the right way to execute a command in python -- it looks like you've gotten shell syntax mixed up with python syntax.  Also, that command greps for the literal string `packet_ip` instead of the _value_ of the variable.

Comment: I thought that might be the problem but how do i fix it?

Comment: I think adding "shell" or sth similar would make the question easier to be found + answered.

Comment: As written, that `if` statement is always true, so this function should just print the command and then print "Already Blocked".  I don't see how it's doing anything else, as you say it is.

Comment: well how should it be modified to fit my purpose? Error on my part, this did write multiple rules BEFORE i added that if statement. After that it prints "Already Blocked" like you said.

Comment: Switch to [python-iptables](https://python-iptables.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#chains-and-tables) this module allow loop rules.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put ***packet_ip*** value insted of it's name
The right code is:

```
def blockip(packet_ip):

   cmd=f"sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -s {packet_ip} -j DROP"
   print cmd

   if [f"$(sudo cat /sbin/iptables --list | grep -- {packet_ip})"]:
        print "Already Blocked"
    else:
        subprocess.call(cmd,shell=True)
        print f"{packet_ip} Has been Blocked"
```

I Used from newer String Formatting That is For python 3.6 or later.